# NoclassDefFoundError:org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Tags: jar, android-ksoap2

I have provide reference of ksoap2 jar in my android project in eclipse.
Still I'm getting the error:
NoclassDefFoundError:org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
Could some one help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your code. we can help only if you post the code

Answer (score 1):

Turns out external jars such as

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

to be put under /libs folder so Eclipse ADT automatically adds your jars to the buildpath of your application. It was a buildpath missing defined class error after all.. I hope this will help you, too!